# Method parameter of dependent type of another implicit method parameter - is it possible?

Tags: scala

(A longish) illustration:

```
// Base trait for different domains. Domains hold value-like things, 
// which have some known relationships between them.
trait Domain {
  type Data
  type IntData <: Data
  type PairData <: Data

  def select(query: Query, data: Data): Data = ???
}

// Base trait for queries. Queries operate in a 
    // specific (but arbitrary) domain.
sealed trait Query {
  def select[D <: Domain](domain: D)(data: domain.Data): domain.Data =
    domain.select(this, data)
}

// Specific queries
case object IdQuery extends Query
case class SuccQuery(val q: Query) extends Query
// ...

// Specific domains
object Values extends Domain {
  sealed abstract class Data
  case class IntData(val data: Int) extends Data
  case class PairData(val a: Data, val b: Data) extends Data
}

object Paths extends Domain {
  // ...
}

object Test {
  def test {
    val query: Query = ???
    val value: Values.Data = ???
    val path: Paths.Data = ???
    val valueResult = query.select(Values)(value)
    val pathResult = query.select(Paths)(path)
  }
}
```

This is a complete working code. In the example, I have a fixed case-hierarchy of structured queries which need to operate on different domains somehow. The common parts of the domains are part of the Domain trait.

Let's look at the select definition in the Query trait: it takes a specific domain (which should be a stable value), and data of a dependent type of this domain. The client passes both the specific domain and the data to the select method. *This is an example of a method in which a parameter is of a dependent type of another (non-implicit) parameter.*

I want to somehow "hide" the domain, so that only the data is passed (the domain being passed implicitly). But I can't quite nail it:

1. If I declare:

   ```
   def select[D <: Domain](implicit domain: D)(data: domain.Data)
   ```

   the compiler complains because implicit method parameters should come last.
2. If I swap the two parameters:

   ```
   def select[D <: Domain](data: domain.Data)(implicit domain: D)
   ```

   the compiler complains about domain being defined after being used:
   *illegal dependent method type: parameter appears in the type of another parameter in the same section or an earlier one*

What can I do to make the domain parameter be passed implicitly?

More generally, is it possible to have a method parameter of a dependent type of another *implicit* method parameter?

Comment: Why don't you just do something like `def select(data: Domain#Data) = { val domain = data.domain; ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this workaround:

```
def select[D <: Domain](implicit domain: D) =
    new Selector[D](domain)

class Selector[D <: Domain](domain: D) {
   def data(data: domain.Data): domain.Data = ???
}

select.data(someData)
```